# QDialog: base class undefined | QT5

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I've got problems with complining this project from Securepoint - http://sourceforge.net/p/securepoint/code/18/tree/

And in result I've got this errors -

> 19:51:14: Running steps for project untitled3... 19:51:14:
>   Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step. 19:51:14: Starting:
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
>     C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug     cl -c -nologo
>   -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"........\5.1.0\msvc2010\include" -I"........\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"........\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"........\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtANGLE" -I"........\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"........\5.1.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.4100.15.jom main.cpp
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(32) : error C2504:
>   'QDialog' : base class undefined
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(41) : error C2653:
>   'QSystemTrayIcon' : is not a class or namespace name
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(41) : error C2061:
>   syntax error : identifier 'MessageIcon'
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(42) : error C2653:
>   'QSystemTrayIcon' : is not a class or namespace name
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(42) : error C2061:
>   syntax error : identifier 'MessageIcon'
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(44) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(44) : error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int jom:
>   C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug
>   [debug\main.obj] Error 2
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(44) : error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(44) :
>   warning C4183: 'getSystrayIcon': missing return type; assumed to be a
>   member function returning 'int'
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(79) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(79) : error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(79) :
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(109) : error C2061:
>   syntax error : identifier 'QTreeWidgetItem'
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(112) : error C2653:
>   'QSystemTrayIcon' : is not a class or namespace name
>   c:\qt\tools\qtcreator\bin\untitled3\preferences.h(112) : error C2061:
>   syntax error : identifier 'ActivationReason'
>   ..\untitled3\main.cpp(106) : error C2653: 'QSystemTrayIcon' : is not a
>   class or namespace name ..\untitled3\main.cpp(106) : error C3861:
>   'isSystemTrayAvailable': identifier not found
>   ..\untitled3\main.cpp(117) : error C2065: 'QSplashScreen' : undeclared
>   identifier ..\untitled3\main.cpp(117) : error C2146: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before identifier 'splash' ..\untitled3\main.cpp(117) :
>   error C3861: 'splash': identifier not found ..\untitled3\main.cpp(119)
>   : error C2065: 'splash' : undeclared identifier
>   ..\untitled3\main.cpp(119) : error C2228: left of '.show' must have
>   class/struct/union
>           type is ''unknown-type'' ..\untitled3\main.cpp(122) : error C2065: 'splash' : undeclared identifier jom:
>   C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-untitled3-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile
>   [debug] Error 2 19:51:17: The process
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2. Error while
>   building/deploying project untitled3 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2010
>   32bit) When executing step 'Make' 19:51:17: Elapsed time: 00:03.

What's the problem?

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator? Did you run qmake?

Comment: You're using Qt5, that project is apparently Qt4-only.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - I'm curious, how could you tell that this project is Qt4-only?

Comment: @Cory Klein: systray.pro has no "QT += widgets" in it. (Adding it might already fix this issue)

Comment: after installation of qt4 i've got new problem - Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options, but compilers are listed in preferences. What's the problem?

Comment: i have resolved the problem with compiling